# Menu hidden by DIV Tailwind

Tags: css, tailwind-css

I do not understand what I am doing wrong (Im a backend guy though). Using Tailwind on VueJS, This menu wont appear above the DIV. I have tried z-index and everything but nothing will make it appear. When I try and force the menu to the front of the screen it wont appear. I have no idea what I am doing wrong.

Image Attached of issue
[image]

```
<section class="bg-white dark:bg-gray-800 min-w-0 flex-1 h-auto flex flex-col lg:order-last">
    <div>
        <ul class="divide-y divide-gray-200">
            <li class="bg-white py-4 px-4">
                <div class="flex space-x-3">
                    <img class="h-6 w-6 rounded-full" src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1480455624313-e29b44bbfde1?ixid=MnwxMjA3fDB8MHxzZWFyY2h8Nnx8bWFsZXxlbnwwfHwwfHw%3D&amp;ixlib=rb-1.2.1&amp;auto=format&amp;fit=crop&amp;w=900&amp;q=60" alt="">
                        <div class="flex-1 space-y-1">
                            <div class="flex items-center justify-between">
                                <h3 class="text-sm font-medium">Username</h3>
                                <p class="text-sm text-gray-500">1h</p>
                            </div>
                            <div class="flex items-center justify-between">
                                <p class="text-sm text-gray-500">Deployed Workcation (2d89f0c8 in master) to production</p>
                                <p class="text-sm bg-blue-500 p-1 rounded text-gray-50"></p>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </li>
                <li class="bg-red-500 bg-opacity-50 text-gray-50 py-4 px-4">
                    <div class="flex space-x-3">
                        <img class="h-6 w-6 rounded-full" src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1566753323558-f4e0952af115?ixid=MnwxMjA3fDB8MHxzZWFyY2h8MTB8fG1hbGV8ZW58MHx8MHx8&amp;ixlib=rb-1.2.1&amp;auto=format&amp;fit=crop&amp;w=900&amp;q=60" alt="">
                            <div class="flex-1 space-y-1">
                                <div class="flex items-center justify-between">
                                    <h3 class="text-sm font-medium">Username</h3>
                                    <p class="text-sm text-gray-500">1h</p>
                                </div>
                                <div class="flex items-center justify-between">
                                    <p class="text-sm text-gray-500">Deployed Workcation (2d89f0c8 in master) to production</p>
                                    <p class="text-sm bg-blue-500 p-1 rounded text-gray-50">whisper</p>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </li>
                    <li class="bg-green-400 bg-opacity-50 py-4 px-4">
                        <div class="flex space-x-3">
                            <img class="h-6 w-6 rounded-full" src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1494790108377-be9c29b29330?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&amp;ixid=eyJhcHBfaWQiOjEyMDd9&amp;auto=format&amp;fit=facearea&amp;facepad=2&amp;w=256&amp;h=256&amp;q=80" alt="">
                                <div class="flex-1 space-y-1">
                                    <div class="flex items-center justify-between">
                                        <h3 class="text-sm font-medium">Username</h3>
                                        <p class="text-sm text-gray-500">1h</p>
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="flex items-center justify-between">
                                        <p class="text-sm text-gray-500">Deployed Workcation (2d89f0c8 in master) to production</p>
                                        <p class="text-sm bg-blue-500 p-1 rounded text-gray-50">mention</p>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </li>
                        <li class="bg-white py-4 px-4">
                            <div class="flex space-x-3">
                                <img class="h-6 w-6 rounded-full" src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1566753323558-f4e0952af115?ixid=MnwxMjA3fDB8MHxzZWFyY2h8MTB8fG1hbGV8ZW58MHx8MHx8&amp;ixlib=rb-1.2.1&amp;auto=format&amp;fit=crop&amp;w=900&amp;q=60" alt="">
                                    <div class="flex-1 space-y-1">
                                        <div class="flex items-center justify-between">
                                            <h3 class="text-sm font-medium">Username</h3>
                                            <p class="text-sm text-gray-500">1h</p>
                                        </div>
                                        <div class="flex items-center justify-between">
                                            <p class="text-sm text-gray-500">Deployed Workcation (2d89f0c8 in master) to production</p>
                                            <p class="text-sm bg-blue-500 p-1 rounded text-gray-50"></p>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </li>
                            <li class="bg-white py-4 px-4">
                                <div class="flex space-x-3">
                                    <img class="h-6 w-6 rounded-full" src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1494790108377-be9c29b29330?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&amp;ixid=eyJhcHBfaWQiOjEyMDd9&amp;auto=format&amp;fit=facearea&amp;facepad=2&amp;w=256&amp;h=256&amp;q=80" alt="">
                                        <div class="flex-1 space-y-1">
                                            <div class="flex items-center justify-between">
                                                <h3 class="text-sm font-medium">Username</h3>
                                                <p class="text-sm text-gray-500">1h</p>
                                            </div>
                                            <div class="flex items-center justify-between">
                                                <p class="text-sm text-gray-500">Deployed Workcation (2d89f0c8 in master) to production</p>
                                                <p class="text-sm bg-blue-500 p-1 rounded text-gray-50"></p>
                                            </div>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                </li>
                                <li class="bg-red-500 bg-opacity-50 text-gray-50 py-4 px-4">
                                    <div class="flex space-x-3">
                                        <img class="h-6 w-6 rounded-full" src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1494790108377-be9c29b29330?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&amp;ixid=eyJhcHBfaWQiOjEyMDd9&amp;auto=format&amp;fit=facearea&amp;facepad=2&amp;w=256&amp;h=256&amp;q=80" alt="">
                                            <div class="flex-1 space-y-1">
                                                <div class="flex items-center justify-between">
                                                    <h3 class="text-sm font-medium">Username</h3>
                                                    <p class="text-sm text-gray-500">1h</p>
                                                </div>
                                                <div class="flex items-center justify-between">
                                                    <p class="text-sm text-gray-500">Deployed Workcation (2d89f0c8 in master) to production</p>
                                                    <p class="text-sm bg-blue-500 p-1 rounded text-gray-50">whisper</p>
                                                </div>
                                            </div>
                                        </div>
                                    </li>
                                    <li class="bg-white py-4 px-4">
                                        <div class="flex space-x-3">
                                            <img class="h-6 w-6 rounded-full" src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1566753323558-f4e0952af115?ixid=MnwxMjA3fDB8MHxzZWFyY2h8MTB8fG1hbGV8ZW58MHx8MHx8&amp;ixlib=rb-1.2.1&amp;auto=format&amp;fit=crop&amp;w=900&amp;q=60" alt="">
                                                <div class="flex-1 space-y-1">
                                                    <div class="flex items-center justify-between">
                                                        <h3 class="text-sm font-medium">Username</h3>
                                                        <p class="text-sm text-gray-500">1h</p>
                                                    </div>
                                                    <div class="flex items-center justify-between">
                                                        <p class="text-sm text-gray-500">Deployed Workcation (2d89f0c8 in master) to production</p>
                                                        <p class="text-sm bg-blue-500 p-1 rounded text-gray-50"></p>
                                                    </div>
                                                </div>
                                            </div>
                                        </li>
                                        <li class="bg-green-400 bg-opacity-50 py-4 px-4">
                                            <div class="flex space-x-3">
                                                <img class="h-6 w-6 rounded-full" src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1494790108377-be9c29b29330?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&amp;ixid=eyJhcHBfaWQiOjEyMDd9&amp;auto=format&amp;fit=facearea&amp;facepad=2&amp;w=256&amp;h=256&amp;q=80" alt="">
                                                    <div class="flex-1 space-y-1">
                                                        <div class="flex items-center justify-between">
                                                            <h3 class="text-sm font-medium">Username</h3>
                                                            <p class="text-sm text-gray-500">1h</p>
                                                        </div>
                                                        <div class="flex items-center justify-between">
                                                            <p class="text-sm text-gray-500">Deployed Workcation (2d89f0c8 in master) to production</p>
                                                            <p class="text-sm bg-blue-500 p-1 rounded text-gray-50">mention</p>
                                                        </div>
                                                    </div>
                                                </div>
                                            </li>
                                            <li class="bg-white py-4 px-4">
                                                <div class="flex space-x-3">
                                                    <img class="h-6 w-6 rounded-full" src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1494790108377-be9c29b29330?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&amp;ixid=eyJhcHBfaWQiOjEyMDd9&amp;auto=format&amp;fit=facearea&amp;facepad=2&amp;w=256&amp;h=256&amp;q=80" alt="">
                                                        <div class="flex-1 space-y-1">
                                                            <div class="flex items-center justify-between">
                                                                <h3 class="text-sm font-medium">Username</h3>
                                                                <p class="text-sm text-gray-500">1h</p>
                                                            </div>
                                                            <div class="flex items-center justify-between">
                                                                <p class="text-sm text-gray-500">Deployed Workcation (2d89f0c8 in master) to production</p>
                                                                <p class="text-sm bg-blue-500 p-1 rounded text-gray-50"></p>
                                                            </div>
                                                        </div>
                                                    </div>
                                                </li>
                                                <li class="bg-white py-4 px-4">
                                                    <div class="flex space-x-3">
                                                        <img class="h-6 w-6 rounded-full" src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1494790108377-be9c29b29330?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&amp;ixid=eyJhcHBfaWQiOjEyMDd9&amp;auto=format&amp;fit=facearea&amp;facepad=2&amp;w=256&amp;h=256&amp;q=80" alt="">
                                                            <div class="flex-1 space-y-1">
                                                                <div class="flex items-center justify-between">
                                                                    <h3 class="text-sm font-medium">Username</h3>
                                                                    <p class="text-sm text-gray-500">1h</p>
                                                                </div>
                                                                <div class="flex items-center justify-between">
                                                                    <p class="text-sm text-gray-500">Deployed Workcation (2d89f0c8 in master) to production</p>
                                                                    <p class="text-sm bg-blue-500 p-1 rounded text-gray-50"></p>
                                                                </div>
                                                            </div>
                                                        </div>
                                                    </li>
                                                    <li class="bg-white py-4 px-4">
                                                        <div class="flex space-x-3">
                                                            <img class="h-6 w-6 rounded-full" src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1494790108377-be9c29b29330?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&amp;ixid=eyJhcHBfaWQiOjEyMDd9&amp;auto=format&amp;fit=facearea&amp;facepad=2&amp;w=256&amp;h=256&amp;q=80" alt="">
                                                                <div class="flex-1 space-y-1">
                                                                    <div class="flex items-center justify-between">
                                                                        <h3 class="text-sm font-medium">Leslie Alexander</h3>
                                                                        <p class="text-sm text-gray-500">1h</p>
                                                                    </div>
                                                                    <div class="flex items-center justify-between">
                                                                        <p class="text-sm text-gray-500">Deployed Workcation (2d89f0c8 in master) to production</p>
                                                                        <p class="text-sm bg-blue-500 p-1 rounded text-gray-50"></p>
                                                                    </div>
                                                                </div>
                                                            </div>
                                                        </li>
                                                        <li class="bg-white py-4 px-4">
                                                            <div class="flex space-x-3">
                                                                <img class="h-6 w-6 rounded-full" src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1480455624313-e29b44bbfde1?ixid=MnwxMjA3fDB8MHxzZWFyY2h8Nnx8bWFsZXxlbnwwfHwwfHw%3D&amp;ixlib=rb-1.2.1&amp;auto=format&amp;fit=crop&amp;w=900&amp;q=60" alt="">
                                                                    <div class="flex-1 space-y-1">
                                                                        <div class="flex items-center justify-between">
                                                                            <h3 class="text-sm font-medium">Username</h3>
                                                                            <p class="text-sm text-gray-500">1h</p>
                                                                        </div>
                                                                        <div class="flex items-center justify-between">
                                                                            <p class="text-sm text-gray-500">Deployed Workcation (2d89f0c8 in master) to production</p>
                                                                            <p class="text-sm bg-blue-500 p-1 rounded text-gray-50"></p>
                                                                        </div>
                                                                    </div>
                                                                </div>
                                                            </li>
                                                            <li class="bg-white py-4 px-4">
                                                                <div class="flex space-x-3">
                                                                    <img class="h-6 w-6 rounded-full" src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1480455624313-e29b44bbfde1?ixid=MnwxMjA3fDB8MHxzZWFyY2h8Nnx8bWFsZXxlbnwwfHwwfHw%3D&amp;ixlib=rb-1.2.1&amp;auto=format&amp;fit=crop&amp;w=900&amp;q=60" alt="">
                                                                        <div class="flex-1 space-y-1">
                                                                            <div class="flex items-center justify-between">
                                                                                <h3 class="text-sm font-medium">Username</h3>
                                                                                <p class="text-sm text-gray-500">1h</p>
                                                                            </div>
                                                                            <div class="flex items-center justify-between">
                                                                                <p class="text-sm text-gray-500">Deployed Workcation (2d89f0c8 in master) to production</p>
                                                                                <p class="text-sm bg-blue-500 p-1 rounded text-gray-50"></p>
                                                                            </div>
                                                                        </div>
                                                                    </div>
                                                                </li>
                                                                <li class="bg-white py-4 px-4">
                                                                    <div class="flex space-x-3">
                                                                        <img class="h-6 w-6 rounded-full" src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1480455624313-e29b44bbfde1?ixid=MnwxMjA3fDB8MHxzZWFyY2h8Nnx8bWFsZXxlbnwwfHwwfHw%3D&amp;ixlib=rb-1.2.1&amp;auto=format&amp;fit=crop&amp;w=900&amp;q=60" alt="">
                                                                            <div class="flex-1 space-y-1">
                                                                                <div class="flex items-center justify-between">
                                                                                    <h3 class="text-sm font-medium">Username</h3>
                                                                                    <p class="text-sm text-gray-500">1h</p>
                                                                                </div>
                                                                                <div class="flex items-center justify-between">
                                                                                    <p class="text-sm text-gray-500">Deployed Workcation (2d89f0c8 in master) to production</p>
                                                                                    <p class="text-sm bg-blue-500 p-1 rounded text-gray-50"></p>
                                                                                </div>
                                                                            </div>
                                                                        </div>
                                                                    </li>
                                                                    <li class="bg-red-500 bg-opacity-50 text-gray-50 py-4 px-4">
                                                                        <div class="flex space-x-3">
                                                                            <img class="h-6 w-6 rounded-full" src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1480455624313-e29b44bbfde1?ixid=MnwxMjA3fDB8MHxzZWFyY2h8Nnx8bWFsZXxlbnwwfHwwfHw%3D&amp;ixlib=rb-1.2.1&amp;auto=format&amp;fit=crop&amp;w=900&amp;q=60" alt="">
                                                                                <div class="flex-1 space-y-1">
                                                                                    <div class="flex items-center justify-between">
                                                                                        <h3 class="text-sm font-medium">Username</h3>
                                                                                        <p class="text-sm text-gray-500">1h</p>
                                                                                    </div>
                                                                                    <div class="flex items-center justify-between">
                                                                                        <p class="text-sm text-gray-500">Deployed Workcation (2d89f0c8 in master) to production</p>
                                                                                        <p class="text-sm bg-blue-500 p-1 rounded text-gray-50">whisper</p>
                                                                                    </div>
                                                                                </div>
                                                                            </div>
                                                                        </li>
                                                                    </ul>
                                                                </div>
                                                            </section>
                                                            <section aria-labelledby="chat-footer" class="h-auto w-full sticky shadow-2xl bg-gradient-to-br from-gray-100 to-gray-300 dark:from-gray-900 dark:to-gray-900 border-l dark:border-gray-800 border-gray-200 bottom-0 min-w-full flex-1 flex flex-col overflow-hidden lg:order-last">
                                                                <div>
                                                                    <span class="pl-10 pt-2 relative z-0 inline-flex shadow-sm rounded-md">
                                                                        <button type="button" class="relative inline-flex items-center px-3 py-1 rounded-l-md border border-gray-300 bg-white dark:border-transparent dark:bg-gray-900 text-sm font-medium text-gray-700 hover:bg-gray-50 focus:z-10 focus:outline-none focus:ring-1 focus:ring-indigo-500 focus:border-indigo-500">
                                                                            <svg
                                                                                xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" fill="none" viewBox="0 0 24 24" stroke="currentColor" class="w-4 h-4 text-gray-600 dark:text-gray-50">
                                                                                <path stroke-linecap="round" stroke-linejoin="round" stroke-width="2" d="M10 20l4-16m4 4l4 4-4 4M6 16l-4-4 4-4"></path>
                                                                            </svg>
                                                                        </button>
                                                                        <button type="button" class="-ml-px relative inline-flex items-center px-3 py-1 border border-gray-300 bg-white dark:border-transparent dark:bg-gray-900 text-sm font-medium text-gray-700 dark:text-gray-50 hover:bg-gray-50 focus:z-10 focus:outline-none focus:ring-1 focus:ring-indigo-500 focus:border-indigo-500"> YouTube </button>
                                                                        <button type="button" class="-ml-px relative inline-flex items-center px-3 py-1 border border-gray-300 bg-white dark:border-transparent dark:bg-gray-900 text-sm font-medium text-gray-700 hover:bg-gray-50 focus:z-10 focus:outline-none focus:ring-1 focus:ring-indigo-500 focus:border-indigo-500">
                                                                            <svg
                                                                                xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 20 20" fill="currentColor" class="w-4 h-4 text-gray-600 dark:text-gray-50">
                                                                                <path fill-rule="evenodd" d="M8 4a4 4 0 100 8 4 4 0 000-8zM2 8a6 6 0 1110.89 3.476l4.817 4.817a1 1 0 01-1.414 1.414l-4.816-4.816A6 6 0 012 8z" clip-rule="evenodd"></path>
                                                                            </svg>
                                                                        </button>
                                                                        <button type="button" class="-ml-px relative inline-flex items-center px-3 py-1 border border-gray-300 bg-white dark:border-transparent dark:bg-gray-900 text-sm font-medium text-gray-700 hover:bg-gray-50 focus:z-10 focus:outline-none focus:ring-1 focus:ring-indigo-500 focus:border-indigo-500">
                                                                            <svg
                                                                                xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" fill="none" viewBox="0 0 24 24" stroke="currentColor" class="w-4 h-4 text-gray-600 dark:text-gray-50">
                                                                                <path stroke-linecap="round" stroke-linejoin="round" stroke-width="2" d="M4 16v1a3 3 0 003 3h10a3 3 0 003-3v-1m-4-8l-4-4m0 0L8 8m4-4v12"></path>
                                                                            </svg>
                                                                        </button>
                                                                        <button type="button" class="-ml-px relative inline-flex items-center px-3 py-1 border border-gray-300 bg-white dark:border-transparent dark:bg-gray-900 text-sm font-medium text-gray-700 hover:bg-gray-50 focus:z-10 focus:outline-none focus:ring-1 focus:ring-indigo-500 focus:border-indigo-500">
                                                                            <svg
                                                                                xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" fill="none" viewBox="0 0 24 24" stroke="currentColor" class="w-4 h-4 text-gray-600 dark:text-gray-50">
                                                                                <path stroke-linecap="round" stroke-linejoin="round" stroke-width="2" d="M8 11V7a4 4 0 118 0m-4 8v2m-6 4h12a2 2 0 002-2v-6a2 2 0 00-2-2H6a2 2 0 00-2 2v6a2 2 0 002 2z"></path>
                                                                            </svg>
                                                                        </button>
                                                                        <div class="relative inline-block text-left">
                                                                            <div>
                                                                                <button id="headlessui-menu-button-1" type="button" aria-haspopup="true" class="-ml-px relative inline-flex items-center px-3 py-2 rounded-r-md border border-gray-300 bg-white dark:bg-gray-900 dark:border-gray-800 dark:hover:bg-gray-600 text-sm font-medium text-gray-700 hover:bg-gray-50 focus:z-10 focus:outline-none focus:ring-1 focus:ring-indigo-500 focus:border-indigo-500" aria-expanded="true" aria-controls="headlessui-menu-items-2"> Send Option 
                                                                                    <svg
                                                                                        xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 20 20" fill="currentColor" class="-mr-1 ml-2 h-5 w-5">
                                                                                        <path fill-rule="evenodd" d="M5.293 7.293a1 1 0 011.414 0L10 10.586l3.293-3.293a1 1 0 111.414 1.414l-4 4a1 1 0 01-1.414 0l-4-4a1 1 0 010-1.414z" clip-rule="evenodd"></path>
                                                                                    </svg>
                                                                                </button>
                                                                            </div>
                                                                            <div aria-labelledby="headlessui-menu-button-1" id="headlessui-menu-items-2" role="menu" tabindex="0" class="overflow-visible origin-top-right absolute bottom-10 mt-2 w-56 rounded-md shadow-lg bg-white dark:bg-gray-900 ring-1 ring-black ring-opacity-5 focus:outline-none">
                                                                                <div class="py-1" role="none">
                                                                                    <a href="#" class="text-gray-700 block px-4 py-2 text-sm" disabled="false" id="headlessui-menu-item-41" role="menuitem" tabindex="-1">Account settings</a>
                                                                                    <a href="#" class="text-gray-700 block px-4 py-2 text-sm" disabled="false" id="headlessui-menu-item-42" role="menuitem" tabindex="-1">Support</a>
                                                                                    <a href="#" class="text-gray-700 block px-4 py-2 text-sm" disabled="false" id="headlessui-menu-item-43" role="menuitem" tabindex="-1">License</a>
                                                                                    <form method="POST" action="#" role="none">
                                                                                        <button type="submit" class="text-gray-700 block w-full text-left px-4 py-2 text-sm" id="headlessui-menu-item-44" role="menuitem" tabindex="-1"> Sign out </button>
                                                                                    </form>
                                                                                </div>
                                                                            </div>
                                                                        </div>
                                                                    </span>
                                                                    <div class="pr-10 pl-10 pb-5  h-full mt-1 flex rounded-md shadow-sm">
                                                                        <div class="relative flex items-stretch flex-grow focus-within:z-10">
                                                                            <div class="absolute inset-y-0 left-0 pl-3 flex items-center pointer-events-none">
                                                                                <svg
                                                                                    xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" fill="none" viewBox="0 0 24 24" stroke="currentColor" class="h-5 w-5 text-gray-400">
                                                                                    <path stroke-linecap="round" stroke-linejoin="round" stroke-width="2" d="M12 4.354a4 4 0 110 5.292M15 21H3v-1a6 6 0 0112 0v1zm0 0h6v-1a6 6 0 00-9-5.197M13 7a4 4 0 11-8 0 4 4 0 018 0z"></path>
                                                                                </svg>
                                                                            </div>
                                                                            <input type="text" name="email" id="email" class="focus:ring-indigo-500 focus:border-indigo-500 block w-full rounded-none rounded-l-md pl-10 sm:text-sm border-gray-300" placeholder="Type your message...">
                                                                            </div>
                                                                            <button id="switchTheme" class="-ml-px bg-indigo-700 relative inline-flex items-center space-x-2 px-4 py-1 border border-gray-300 text-sm font-medium rounded-r-md text-gray-700 bg-transparent hover:bg-gray-100 focus:outline-none focus:ring-1 focus:ring-indigo-500 focus:border-indigo-500">
                                                                                <svg
                                                                                    xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" fill="none" viewBox="0 0 24 24" stroke="currentColor" class="h-5 w-5 text-gray-50">
                                                                                    <path stroke-linecap="round" stroke-linejoin="round" stroke-width="2" d="M10.325 4.317c.426-1.756 2.924-1.756 3.35 0a1.724 1.724 0 002.573 1.066c1.543-.94 3.31.826 2.37 2.37a1.724 1.724 0 001.065 2.572c1.756.426 1.756 2.924 0 3.35a1.724 1.724 0 00-1.066 2.573c.94 1.543-.826 3.31-2.37 2.37a1.724 1.724 0 00-2.572 1.065c-.426 1.756-2.924 1.756-3.35 0a1.724 1.724 0 00-2.573-1.066c-1.543.94-3.31-.826-2.37-2.37a1.724 1.724 0 00-1.065-2.572c-1.756-.426-1.756-2.924 0-3.35a1.724 1.724 0 001.066-2.573c-.94-1.543.826-3.31 2.37-2.37.996.608 2.296.07 2.572-1.065z"></path>
                                                                                    <path stroke-linecap="round" stroke-linejoin="round" stroke-width="2" d="M15 12a3 3 0 11-6 0 3 3 0 016 0z"></path>
                                                                                </svg>
                                                                                <span class="text-gray-50">Send</span>
                                                                            </button>
                                                                        </div>
                                                                    </div>
                                                                </section>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The footer `<section>` tag has `overflow-hidden` set, which cuts off any elements that extend out of the border of the `<section>`. Since your menu should extend out the top of the `<section>`, this isn't what you want. Removing this utility appears to fix the issue.

When debugging designs with lots of these Tailwind classes all over the place, it can be helpful to look at things in your browser DevTools to avoid being overwhelmed or missing things.

`z-index` can be tricky to work with, especially since it's commonly misunderstood. A lot of the time, you shouldn't need to use z-index, so seeing if other strategies work could reduce complexity and make your sites more resilient. For more information on z-index, check out Josh W. Comeau's [excellent blog post](https://www.joshwcomeau.com/css/stacking-contexts/).

Comment: ok but removing that still doesnt fix the grander issues.

Comment: hmm, removing the `overflow-hidden` worked for me (see https://play.tailwindcss.com/ugrjb7sCSK, line 232). am I misunderstanding your question?

Comment: You understood it correctly. For some reason when I removed it in DevTools it didn't initialize it for some unknown reason. Now onto figuring out the scroll issue. Thanks so much!!!